# hibernate createSQLQuery doesn't have addEntity method

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to use the addEntity method of a hibernate Query, but it only has a "setEntity" method?

```
  Query query = session.createSQLQuery("...");
  query.addEntity(MyClass.class); // doesn't exist, but setEntity method does?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you either have to use the right class, this works:

```
  SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("...");
  sqlQuery.addEntity(MyClass.class);
```

Or chain it, this works:

```
  Query query = session.createSQLQuery("...").addEntity(MyClass.class);
```